# Can't create icon from hex digit

Tags: javascript, angular, ionicons

I want to be able to take a string such as `f37f` and return `"\uf37f"` from my function.  The strings correspond to icons.

If I `return "\uf37f"` the function works, but it does not work if I try this:

```
return `\\u${iconString}`;
```

The icon shows up as text.  I cannot simply concatenate `"\u"` and my icon as this throws a `hexadecimal digit expected` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [string.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode):

Example from the documentation:

```
String.fromCharCode(0x2014)       // returns "—"
```

That takes a number, not a string, so first you'll need to parse the string into a number, e.g.:

```
parseInt("f37f")
```

You can store that in an intermediate variable or combine them into a single expression.

```
String.fromCharCode(parseInt("f37f"))
```